# I hope you're hungry

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Somsak：May I bring you a salad?
>   Susan：Oh yes. What do you recommend today?
>   Somsak：I recommend rose-petal salad. Special for new friends.
>   Susan：[to Harry] Rose-petal salad?
>   Harry：Why not?
>   Somsak：I'll take care of everything. [He leaves.]
>   Susan：I **hope** you're hungry.
>   Harry：What? Oh, yes. Starving.

I find this explanation in a dictionary:

> 8. (tr; takes a clause as object) to trust, expect, or believe: we hope that this is satisfactory.

Dose *hope* in my example sentence mean *to believe*? If that is the case, instead of using believe or think, why would one use *hope* here? Is there any difference in nuance between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is used here. It means wish or desire. The person has made food and hope that the person is hungry or all the food will go to waste.

Using trust, expect, think, or believe here means that the person assumes that Harry is hungry. This is probably partially true, but the passage you gave makes no indication of that.